# Is there any algorithm to find the maximum value of this?

Tags: max

Let X be a n*n matrix For any rectangle in X,
let `t=(a+d)-(b+c)`

Where a and d are left top and right bottom each, and b and c are right top and left bottom each.

The problem is to find the maximum value of t. Is there any algorithm whose time complexity is less then `Θ(n^3)`?

Comment: I believe you are going to get better help on one of math SE or computer science SE.